# UITextField.becomeFirstResponder() Crash iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uikit

Whenever I try to make a call to text fields first responder, my app will crash and provide the following exception:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot get value with size 16. The type encoded as {CGRect={CGPoint=dd}{CGSize=dd}} is expected to be 32 bytes'
```

Does anyone know what causes this error? My app is currently in the market and need assistance with fixing this error before I release an update.

Comment: Please add your code.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue. Since there were a lot of things deprecated in the latest iOS update, I forgot to take out my keyboard code that was deprecated. I was using this before:

```
let keyboardHeight = (notification[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgSizeValue.height
```

Now I am using the following:

```
let keyboardSize = (notification[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
```

Hope this helps anyone in the future.